# Dem_OperationCycleStateType is not available on Dem specification

Tags: simulink, autosar

I want to learn how to use diagnostic operation cycle block in Autosar Blockset.
this block consist of two operation, `SetOperationCycleState` and `GetOperationCycleState`.

To set an operation cycle state the Simulink defines a prebuilt enumeration called `Dem_OperationCycleStateType`, but I can not find any information about this type in AR documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the AUTOSAR Version you are looking at. It seems in AUTOSAR 4.4.0, the interfaces `Dem_SetOperationCycleState() / Dem_GetOperationCycleState()` are replaced by `Dem_RestartOperationCycle()`. And this new interface does not need a state argument.

In AUTOSAR 4.3.1, the definition is chapter 8.6.1.15
Dem_OperationCycleStateType

[SWS_Dem_00929] Dem_OperationCycleStateType

Type: Derived from uint8

Description: This type contains operation cycle state values, which can be reported via Dem_SetOperationCycleState()/
Dem_GetOperationCycleState().

Range:

- DEM_CYCLE_STATE_START - 0x00 - Start/restart the operation
  cycle
- DEM_CYCLE_STATE_END - 0x01 - End the operation cyclein